# New EU Cookie law - how do I know if people have opted out?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

According to new EU laws I have to ask my users to opt into having cookies installed on their computers.

So every time I want to set a cookie I have to see if the user has opted in and if they haven't I shouldn't set the cookie.

When they come to the website a popup will ask if they want to opt in. Should they click "no" I cannot put a cookie on their computer to say they've clicked no. How do I then know, as they go through the website, that they've clicked "no"?

Do I just have to show the popup every page they go to? Or store it in a session variable? (is using sessions still ok under the new law? I assume a cookie is set with the session key?).

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law and legislation. Consult a lawyer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer but I've been reading up on this recently and it is quite clear under the new regulations not every cookie is considered equal and opting in is not required for all of them.

The regulations are most keen on ensuring that cookies that allow tracking of users actions/data between websites must have an opt in, at the other extreme, cookies that contain no personal information and are, for example, only used for security on one particular site (like a session cookie) may not need permission at all.

The UK ICO website has some very clear pages & PDFs (including: http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications.aspx) on the subject and is definitely worthwhile visiting.

Comment: Any chance you could clarify whether we're "allowed" to set a cookie to remember the actual Cookie choice?

Comment: I only know what I have read on the ICO site, but the emphasis was very much on not collecting personal information without the user's permission and I can't see how a cookie that is only a yes/no flag for the cookie choice could be construed as personal information.

Comment: what about HTML5 local storage? are we forced to use it instead of cookies? :)